# Webpack @azure/storage-blob node-fetch AbortSignal issue

Tags: node.js, azure, webpack, azure-blob-storage, terser

I am facing one particular issue often talked about at various places the link I will share later. The problem is related to the webpack bundling. My nodeJS application uses @azure/storage-blob library to fetch the data while it works perfectly fine when not bundled but as soon as I bundle the application using webpack the app starts to throw the following error:

Stack Trace: *TypeError: Expected signal to be an instanceof AbortSignal at new Request (webpack://ECPNodeAPI/./node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.mjs?:1229:10) at eval (webpack://ECPNodeAPI/./node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.mjs?:1416:19) at new Promise () at fetch (webpack://ECPNodeAPI/./node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.mjs?:1414:9) at NodeFetchHttpClient2.eval (webpack://ECPNodeAPI/./node_modules/@azure/core-http/es/src/nodeFetchHttpClient.js?:69:74) at step (webpack://ECPNodeAPI/./node_modules/@azure/core-http/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js?:195:19) at Object.eval [as next] (webpack://ECPNodeAPI/./node_modules/@azure/core-http/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js?:142:14) at eval (webpack://ECPNodeAPI/./node_modules/@azure/core-http/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js?:128:67) at new Promise () at __awaiter (webpack://ECPNodeAPI/./node_modules/@azure/core-http/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js?:110:10)*

The issue is mentioned in node-fetch issues: https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/784. While the latest version claims to have this issue fixed. But @azure/storage-blob is using the old version of node-fetch.

Solutions that I have tried but no luck.

- Using yarn resolutions to be able to use the latest version of node-fetch and then bundle. Tried not working.
- By setting minimize to false and using the terser plugin. I tried various combinations yet no luck like here https://github.com/Azure/ms-rest-nodeauth/issues/83#issuecomment-690927491

Does anyone else have any other workaround for the same?

Comment: Hey, how are you. 
Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: hi, yes actually i was able to do that using terser plugin. I have answered my own question.

Comment: Thanks, you should mark it as the best response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to come over with this problem using Terser Plugin. Here is the webpack.config.js file that might help you fix the issue.

```js
import path from 'path';
import TerserPlugin from 'terser-webpack-plugin';
import nodeExternals from 'webpack-node-externals';

const __dirname = path.dirname('.');

const isProd = true; // process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

export default {
  mode: isProd ? 'production' : 'development',
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  entry: './index.mjs',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'api.bundle.js',
    clean: true,
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          keep_fnames: /AbortSignal/,
          sourceMap: true,
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: 'raw-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'esbuild-loader',
        options: {
          //    loader: 'jsx',  // Remove this if you're not using JSX
          target: 'es2018', // Syntax to compile to (see options below for possible values)
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'esbuild-loader',
        options: {
          loader: 'ts', // Or 'ts' if you don't need tsx
          target: 'es2015',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Please mark it as the best response. It did work for my Azure project.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `esbuild` add the `--keep-names` flag and that should resolve this as well.